# Is there a way to automatically add a whitespace upon completion in company-mode?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, code-completion

I use company-mode a lot on natural language completion with the local dictionary. I am wondering if there is a way to automatically add a whitespace upon completion.

For example, currently when I type `abili` and select the first candidate `ability`, my insert point is right after `y|`. Is there a way that the company-mode can add a space so my insert point is after `y |`?

I could not find any related information on this but [this issue](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/217#issue-47555074) mentioned  a space is added after completion in the Eshell mode. Apparently this is exactly what I want.

The issue mentioned the function `completion-at-point`. Is there a way that I can change or have a function that I can override the current completion mechanism?

Thanks! I’d really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a hook to `company-after-completion-hook` that would be called after completion with any of your company backends, eg.

```
(defun my-company-after-completion-hook (&rest _ignored)
  ;; this would be called with the completion candidate, so you could
  ;; modify it to insert spaces based on the candidate
  (just-one-space))

;; or setq-local in a mode hook, eg. for text-mode/org-mode or wherever you are
;; completing with dictionary words 
(setq company-after-completion-hook #'my-company-after-completion-hook)
```

If you only wanted to add space after completing with a specific backend you could see if the backend already implements a `post-completion` action, otherwise you could probably advise it.

Comment: Hi, based on your function, I modified the last "(setq" line as ` (setq company-completion-finished-hook #'my-company-after-completion-hook)` so that the white space will only be added when the completion is successful. Thanks again for your answer.